# Can I reuse mods from found weapons?

Tags: fallout-4

Can I reuse mods from found weapons? I always recycled the weapons, but it seems that I have to build every mod for every weapon from scratch.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes! However, you'll need to remove the mods or change them out for a different part at a crafting station, *before* you scrap or sell the weapon.

For instance, if you find an .50 Cal hunting rifle, and want the receiver, you'll need to replace it with a different receiver, which you'll need the availiable parts to make (or just to have a different hunting rifle receiver in your inventory/workbench). You'll then have the .50 receiver in your inventory as a mod that you can add to any weapon that it's compatible with.

Comment: +1, This is an alternative to taking the crafting perks. I have a character with no ranks in Science or Gun Nut with some tricked out guns. It can sometimes be worth buying guns from vendors just to take a mod off them.